# How to POST a multipart/form-data using Power Query's Web.Contents

Tags: excel, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, powerquery

In Power Query, I can download data from Web using the Web.Contents function, but there's an api that required the request to contains multipart/form data in the following format

`"__rdxml"=<*Some data*>`

So how do you do this using the Web.Contents function?

I tried, doing

```
...
PostContent = "__rdxml=<*Some data*>",
Source Web.Contents(url,Content=Text.ToBinary(PostContent))
...
```

But server response with `400 Bad Request`.

I checked the raw request with Fiddler, it seem like the request is not sending with `content-type=multipart/form-data` header.

I tried manually adding the content-type header with `content-type=multipart/form-data`, but that doesn't work either. Same `400 Bad Request` in the response.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

multipart/form-data is a fairly complicated encoding, requiring a bunch of MIME-specific headers. I would first try to see if you can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead:

```
let
    actualUrl = "http://some.url",
    record = [__rdxml="some data"],
    body = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(record)),
    options = [Headers =[#"Content-type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"], Content=body],
    result = Web.Contents(actualUrl, options)
in
    result
```

EDIT: I've come up with an example of using multipart/form-data with Power Query. It's at https://gist.github.com/CurtHagenlocher/b21ce9cddf54e3807317

Comment: If you require multiple values in the body, you can add them as comma separated values in the record as an array of values. Also, on the next line for readability. ie record = [field1="some data", field2="some data" ]

Comment: i am referring to this 8year old query and applying the same options, my request is working fine in Postman but power query is still giving 400 Bad request