# How to convert JSON-string to Binary using a Record? Web.Contents + POST + Power Query

Tags: powerquery

Web.Contents method takes Content as Binary

I use this code. It works

```
query = "{
    ""field1"" : ""value1"",
    ""field2"" : ""value2"",
    ""field3"" : {
        ""sub_field_3_1"" : [""value_3_1_1"", ""value_3_1_2"", ""value_3_1_1""],
        ""sub_field_3_2"" : [""value_3_2_1"", ""value_3_2_2"", ""value_3_2_1""]
        }
    }",

content = Text.ToBinary(query),

Web.Contents("https://my_url", [
    Headers = [#"Content-Type"="text/xml; charset=utf-8"],
    Content=content
])
```

I understand, it is not a good workaround, because there is no reason to make double-conversions. But I could not find a way how to apply a Record, and it should look like this:

```
record = [
    field1 = value1,
    field2 = value2,
    field3 = [
        sub_field_3_1 = {value_3_1_1, value_3_1_2, value_3_1_1},
        sub_field_3_2 = {value_3_2_1, value_3_2_2, value_3_2_1}
    ]
],

content = SOME_CONVERTER(record),

Web.Contents("https://my_url", [
    Headers = [#"Content-Type"="text/xml; charset=utf-8"],
    Content = content
])
```

Tried to use **Uri.BuildQueryString** ([How to POST a multipart/form-data using Power Query's Web.Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361628/how-to-post-a-multipart-form-data-using-power-querys-web-contents)) but it does not form Binary properly

```
record = [
    field1 = value1,
    field2 = value2,
    field3 = [
        sub_field_3_1 = {value_3_1_1, value_3_1_2, value_3_1_1},
        sub_field_3_2 = {value_3_2_1, value_3_2_2, value_3_2_1}
    ]
],

content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(record)),

Web.Contents("https://my_url", [
    Headers = [#"Content-Type"="text/xml; charset=utf-8"],
    Content=content
]
```

Is there some better workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, your hard-coded JSON string is one of the better solutions.

It's less than ideal, but you could roll your own value-to-JSON transforming function like `toJson`:

```
let
    record = [
        field1 = "value1",
        field2 = "value2",
        field3 = [
            sub_field_3_1 = {"value_3_1_1", null, 3.2},
            sub_field_3_2 = {"value_3_2_1", "value_3_2_2", "value_3_2_1"}
        ]
    ],

    toJson = (v as any) as text =>
      if v is null then "null" else 
      if v is logical or v is number then Text.From(v) else
      if v is text then """" & Text.Replace(Text.Replace(v, "\", "\\"), """", "\""") & """" else
      if v is list then "[" & Text.Combine(List.Transform(v, @toJson), ", ") & "]" else
      if v is record then "{" & 
        Text.Combine(List.Transform(
          Record.FieldNames(v),
          (n) => @toJson(n) & ": " & @toJson(Record.Field(v, n))), ", ")
        & "}" else
      error "not implemented",  

    jsonText = toJson(record)
in
    jsonText
```

Some deficiencies compared to what a real `Json.FromValue` library function should do:

- only primitive text escaping

  - see [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for all the special characters you'd need to escape
- doesn't handle cyclic M values, special not-numbers, or other types of value types
- will choke on very large values (string concat will use a lot of memeory)

Comment: SOME_CONVERTER == Json.FromValue @Carl

Answer (score 2):

SOME_CONVERTER == Json.FromValue

```
let
    record = [
        field1 = "value1",
        field2 = "value2",
        field3 = [
            sub_field_3_1 = {"value_3_1_1", "value_3_1_2", "value_3_1_1"},
            sub_field_3_2 = {"value_3_2_1", "value_3_2_2", "value_3_2_1"}
        ]
    ],
    content = Json.FromValue(record),
    web=Web.Contents("https://my_url", [
        Headers = [#"Content-Type"="text/xml; charset=utf-8"],
        Content = content
    ])
in
    web
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you are using any recent update :)