# Add Body "form-data" to a post request in Power Query - Power BI

Tags: post, request, powerbi, powerquery

I want to make a post request to an API and get back json result in Power BI. The request works correctly in Postman. With PowerQuery i'm getting a "invalid credential" from the server.

This is the code i'm using in Power BI

```
let
    url = "https://url/private/webService/?date_deb=2019-07-01&date_fin=2019-08-31",
    body  = "{ ""rest_mdp"": ""b6cfsdffdg2bb173rgfgddfga62b3e"" }",
    Parsed_JSON = Json.Document(body),
    BuildQueryString = Uri.BuildQueryString(Parsed_JSON),
    webdata = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content=Text.ToBinary(body) ] ))
in
    webdata
```

This is a screen of the result in postman :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Content` is the right way to add a POST body. It's probably easiest to use Fiddler to inspect Power BI's POST request ([here's a how-to guide](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/05/03/troubleshooting-data-refresh-performance-issues-with-odata-data-sources-in-power-bi-and-excel-using-fiddler/)), and compare it to Postman.

If the error message is invalid credential, then the problem is possibly with the Authentication header.

Comment: I've used Fiddler to discover that my "rest_mdp" was not sent. I've found a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361628/how-to-post-a-multipart-form-data-using-power-querys-web-contents . I use now "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json"